# Linux daemon as external agent polling PHP webapp

Tags: php, linux, daemon, worker

**Situation:** I'm building a Laravel application that needs external agents running on Linux servers as a daemon, polling the Laravel application for "work" to be done and sending results back to the app.

The agent must connect to the application, not the application to the agent (because we do not want to open firewall ports on the Linux servers)

**Question 1:** What programming language would you suggest for this daemon?

**Question 2:** Is there a standard framework or polling protocol which I can use?

Comment: I'm sure that Laravel has some console interface.  You could just run a local cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** What programming language would you suggest for this daemon?

For now I started to use PHP (PHP-CLI) for the agent. (Because I use PHP on the server side as well, this was easiest)

**Question 2:** Is there a standard framework or polling protocol which I can use?

I started with Laravel Passport API: https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport

In combination with Guzzle: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/